# How do I add a card effect to my card ScriptableObject in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, methods, scriptable-object

I have this ScriptableObject and I would like to add an effect to each card at creation; I have a script called "EffectManager" that has some methods as effects.

This is my card script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Card", menuName = "Card")]
public class Card : ScriptableObject
{
    public string m_cardName;
    public Sprite m_sprite;

    public int m_manaCost;
    public int m_health;
    public int m_attack;
}
```

and this is my EffectManager Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class EffectManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Deck dk;
    Hand hnd;
    Player p1;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        dk = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Deck>();
        hnd = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Hand>();
        jg1 = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    }

    public void draw(int num)
    {
        jg1.DrawCards(num);
    }

    public void discard()
    {
        hnd.hand.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    private void mill()
    {
        dk.deck.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

How can I make so each card I create has an effect linked to it that activates when conditions are met? (in this case it would be when the card is summoned)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pattern I like to call "Scriptable Behavior" which basically simply consists of another `ScriptableObject` type and implement different effects like e.g.

```
public abstract class CardEffect : ScriptableObject
{
    // You can give that the signature (parameters and return type) you want/need of course
    // Every type inherited from this HAS TO implement this method
    public abstract void ExecuteEffect (EffectManager effectManager);
}
```

Now you can implement certain configurable effects like e.g.

```
public class DrawEffect : CardEffect
{
    // Adjust how many cards are drawn
    public int amount;

    public override void ExecuteEffect (EffectManager effectManager)
    {
        effectManager.draw(amount);
    }
}
```

Or e.g.

```
public class DrawAndDiscardEffect : DrawEffect
{
    public override void ExecuteEffect (EffectManager effectManager)
    {
        // First do whatever the parent class implements
        base.ExecuteEffect(effectManager);

        // Additionally discard the same amount of cards
        for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            effectManager.discard();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally you would have an additional field in the card definitions. Personally I would even use an array so you can totally flexible combine different kinds of effects without having to inherit one from another like

```
public class Card : ScriptableObject
{
    public CardEffect[] effects;

    ...

    public void Summon(EffectManager effectManager)
    {
        foreach(var effect in effects)
        {
            effect.ExecuteEffect(effectManager);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is that something in your setup actually calls that

```
// Wherever you get these from
EffectManager effectManager;
Card someCard;

someCard.Summon(effectManager);
```

---

This then can easily be extended to the comolexibility you need. You could e.g. instead of having a `Summon` method and only one collection of effects have yet another ScriptableObject type called `EffectCondition` and implement different types of conditions which will then run their attached effect collection.

Then the central controller could go through all cards and rather call e.g. `CheckCondition` and then every card goes through all attached conditional setups, checks if the according condition is fulfilled and then executes all effects bound to that condition ;)

Comment: Question though: What I have seen is, people create Scriptable Object using[CreateAssetMenu(attribute)]. If I have so many Scriptable Behaviour( I have 60 cards, each has 4 CardUpgrade), How do I create those assets?

Comment: @ZonyZhao well, you would create them yes .. the one or other way you have to fill in this information. Do all your 60 cards have completely unique effects?

Comment: It's not visual effects, but card behaviour, like, the usage of the card. Of course they are different. Maybe I can abstract them to a certain degree, but it's at lease 20-30 I guess? U can just take Hearthstone card as reference.

Comment: In that case I would probably still go with ScriptableObjects.. or just have "normal" classes derived from a base card and instantiate them where needed via reflection e.g.